# Is it possible to output word array in Python similar to CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash)

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, hmac, cryptojs

Is there a way to convert a hash to a word array in Python as in JS?

In JS with CryptoJS I can use: `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(hash)` which will output the word array.

I've tried googling it but cannot seem to find how to do that in Python.

Javascript example:

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

var hash = "c8f3ab9777da89748851932d3446b197450bb12fa9b9136ad708734291a6c60c";

console.log(hash);
```

I cannot figure out how to get similar output with hmac and hashlib libraries in Python but I expect the output something like this:

```
{ words:
   [ -923554921,
     2010810740,
     -2007919827,
     877048215,
     1158394159,
     -1447488662,
     -687312062,
     -1851341300 ],
  sigBytes: 32 }
```

Update:
I need to have an output in the exact same format (spacing, indents, new lines) to produce a subsequent hash from the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in Python but it's not builtin as part of any crypto library that I am aware of.

A simple implementation (requires Python 3):

```py
hash = "c8f3ab9777da89748851932d3446b197450bb12fa9b9136ad708734291a6c60c"

# Convert hex-encoded data into a byte array
hash_bytes = bytes.fromhex(hash)

# Split bytes into 4-byte chunks (32-bit integers) and convert
# The integers in your example a big-endian, signed integers
hash_ints = [
    int.from_bytes(hash_bytes[i:i+4], "big", signed=True) 
    for i in range(0, len(hash_bytes), 4)
]

# Print result
print({"words": hash_ints, "sigBytes": len(hash_bytes)})
```

This will output: `{'words': [-923554921, 2010810740, -2007919827, 877048215, 1158394159, -1447488662, -687312062, -1851341300], 'sigBytes': 32}`

Hope that helps.

Comment: How to have an output in the exact same formatting as in the original question, for example, space between 1st parenthesis and words, each int starts at new line etc? The reason I am asking is that I need to further hash the output and because the suggested output doesn't match the formatting it outputs different hash. I'll edit the question as well.

Comment: My answer gives you the first part. You can do some formatting to generate the exact output you are after. One question though, why? The original string is the hex-encoded hash...